# Multiple single channel matrix converted to single multi channel matrix

Tags: opencv, matrix, computer-vision

i am working in opencv c++ api with matrices

I have 4 single channel Mat that i will like to merge into one 4 channel matrix. It is basically the rgba channels i have in 4 matrices and want to combine into one rgba image/matrix. Anyone who knows how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [cv::merge](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=merge#void%20merge%28const%20Mat%2a%20mv,%20size_t%20count,%20OutputArray%20dst%29) to do what you want. One possible usage:

```
cv::Mat r,g,b,a;

//Fill r,g,b,a with data

cv::Mat result;
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;

channels.push_back(r);
channels.push_back(g);
channels.push_back(b);
channels.push_back(a);

cv::merge(channels, result);
```